# Labelling sentences based on specific punctuations

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have list of sentences in which words need to be labelled based on particular punctuation. If one of the punctuation characters comes after a word in a sentence it should put a label as a name of punctuation character. Sentences are already splitted into words and stored in a list.

```
sentence = ['I', 'like', 'to', 'read', 'a', 'book,', 'dont', 'you?']
targets = {',': 'COMMA', '.': 'PERIOD', '?': 'QUESTION'}
no_punctuation = "EMPTY"


for word in sentence:
    for key, value in targets.items():
        if word.endswith(key):
            word = word.rstrip(key)
            print("{}\t{}".format(word, value))
        else:
            print("{}\t{}".format(word, no_punctuation))
```

Seems there are many irrelevant copies printed to the output which is not desired

```
I EMPTY
I EMPTY
I EMPTY
like EMPTY
like EMPTY
like EMPTY
to EMPTY
to EMPTY
to EMPTY
read EMPTY
read EMPTY
read EMPTY
a EMPTY
a EMPTY
a EMPTY
book COMMA
book EMPTY
book EMPTY
dont EMPTY
dont EMPTY
dont EMPTY
you? EMPTY
you? EMPTY
you QUESTION
```

Expected output:

```
I EMPTY
like EMPTY
to EMPTY
read EMPTY
a EMPTY
book COMMA
dont EMPTY
you QUESTION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sentence = ['I', 'like', 'to', 'read', 'a', 'book,', 'dont', 'you?']
targets = {',': 'COMMA', '.': 'PERIOD', '?': 'QUESTION'}
no_punctuation = "EMPTY"


for word in sentence:
    found = False
    for key, value in targets.items():
        if word.endswith(key):
            found = True
            word = word.rstrip(key)
            print("{}\t{}".format(word, value))
            break
    if not found:
        print("{}\t{}".format(word, no_punctuation))
```